# addEventListener in Vue not firing, though event shows up in dev tools

Tags: vue.js, addeventlistener, event-listener

I'm using a plugin, which dynamically adds a < ul > with < li >s to the DOM (a dropdown-menu when I hit '#'). I'm trying to add to them an event. The event shows up in the dev tools, but still nothing happens when I click them. What am I doing wrong?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error **and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*.** Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: While you are correct, and he/she didn't supply a direct link, I noticed the URL in their screenshot and used that to test with :) Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you just need to read the documentation for [Tribute/vue-tribute](https://github.com/zurb/tribute#a-collection) ..

Does something like this work?

---

**NEW:** https://codesandbox.io/s/7mp416jnjq

**OLD:** https://codesandbox.io/s/8xv5ll6myl

---

I removed the added event listener for `console.log("AAAA");` within your `updated()` hook... I also added the following to each of your tribute collections, inside of your `data` prop:

```
selectTemplate: (item) => {
  this.writeToConsole('hi@');
  return (
    "@" +
    item.original.key +
    " <h1><b> ~~ Check your console ~~  </b></h1>"
  );
}
```

---

Added test method:

```
methods: {
    writeToConsole(data) {
      console.log(data);
    },
    /* ... more code here */
},
```

---

Full data prop:

```
  data() {
    return {
      isMounted: false,
      options: {
        fillAttr: "key",
        collection: [
          {
            trigger: "@",
            values: [
              { key: "CollinHenderson" },
              { key: "SarahDrasner" },
              { key: "EvanYou" },
              { key: "AdamWathan" }
            ],
            selectTemplate: (item) => {
              this.writeToConsole('hi@');
              return (
                "@" +
                item.original.key +
                " <h1><b> ~~ Check your console ~~  </b></h1>"
              );
            }
          },
          {
            trigger: "#",
            values: [{ key: "foo" }, { key: "bar" }, { key: "baz" }],
            selectTemplate: (item) => {
              this.writeToConsole('hello');
              return (
                "#" +
                item.original.key +
                "  <h1><b> ~~ Check your console ~~  </b></h1>"
              );
            }
          }
        ],
        noMatchTemplate() {
          return "<li class'noMatches' style='background: #d88686;color: #fff;'>No matches found</li>";
        }
      }
    };
  },
```

Comment: thanks, but the issue wasn't the log :) 
it's about the method that shall be triggered when clicking the element. But I can't fire it in the data (selectTemplate). Also I cant just put its content there instead, because it uses references.

Comment: Yea so add that method inside that same function..... `selectTemplate` is a callback that gets fired after you select an item. That's what my answer shows. You can put anything you want there.....firing a method after selecting an item is exactly what you were trying to accomplish with a click event handler. It's built into the plug-in for you. You don't have to recreate it. Read their docs.

Comment: But it doesnt accept neither 
  `this.TransferTextAndHighLite();` 
nor
 `this.$refs["colorDiv"].innerHTML = this.$refs["transpDiv"].innerHTML` 
nor
`document.getElementById("colorDiv").innerHTML = document.getElementById("transpDiv").innerHTML;`

Comment: You have to use arrow functions.. see my updated answer, with a test method displaying how you can use the `this` keyword (in order to access methods)......

Comment: No problem. I am not - honestly, I just read the docs.  I have come to know most plugins like that supply their own callbacks for things like this, and I know from my (limited) work with Vue, that if you want to retain context, and use the `this` keyword in callbacks, you have to use arrow functions. Which I believe is more of an ES6 'feature'.  If this answered your question, would you mind accepting my answer? Thanks!